# C# MVC .Net Core Form, strongly typed Form, not working ( 404 error )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, strongly-typed-view

I am very new to C#. I am just trying to get an MVC form to work to understand how information is passed from the view to controller. I am trying to submit my form and have the page updated with the input ( eventually so I can figure out how to pass the form data to an XML file. But I get an error when I hit submit on the form. Need some help please. I can't find a simple tutorial to walk me through this.

My files are : User.cs ( model), AddACustomerController.sc ( controller), and AddACustomer.cshtml ( view)

MODEL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication10.Models
{
    public class User
    {


        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        public string Role { get; set; }



    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using WebApplication10.Models;

namespace WebApplication10.Controllers
{
    public class AddACustomerController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserForm(Models.User person)
        {
            string firstname = person.FirstName;
            string lastname = person.LastName;
            string role = person.Role;

            ViewBag.n = person.FirstName;
            ViewBag.l = person.LastName;
            ViewBag.r = person.Role;

            return View("UserForm");
        }
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
@model WebApplication10.Models.User

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddACustomer";
}

<h1>AddACustomer</h1>

<h4 style="color:purple">
    <b>First Name:</b>    @ViewBag.f <br />
    <b>Last Name:</b>  @ViewBag.l <br />
    <b>Role:</b> @ViewBag.r
</h4>
<hr />


@using (Html.BeginForm("UserForm", "AddACustomer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Person Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name: </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name: </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Role: </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, new List<SelectListItem>
               { new SelectListItem{Text="Administrator", Value="Administrator"},
                 new SelectListItem{Text="Data Entry", Value="Data Entry"},
                 new SelectListItem{Text="Sales", Value="Sales"},
                 new SelectListItem{Text="Networking", Value="Networking"}
                 }, "Please select")
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

}
```

PICTURE OF VIEW:

[image]

PICTURE OF ERROR WHEN I HIT SUBMIT BUTTON ON FORM:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is

```
return View("UserForm");
```

It is probably easiest for you to just keep all your routes called Index.  You can have

```
Index() 
Index(Models.User)
```

Otherwise you'll need to create another .cshtml (View) called UserForm.cshtml.

Comment: Thanks BillRob. I've tried a few variations based on your input, but when I submit the URL goes from " https://localhost:44351/Home/AddACustomer" to " https://localhost:44351/AddACustomer/UserForm".

Comment: You'll need to also change your form post.  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AddACustomer", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: Thanks Bill- do you know of a good tutorial besides the //learn.microsoft.com ?

Comment: No Vynce, I do not have any other recommendations.  The MS site is much better than it was years ago.